# Where to store libraries required by an applet in order to avoid download them every time applet in oppened

Tags: java, windows, applet

I have developed an applet, it require lots of libraries (around 5mb in .jar files), I know exactly in what pcs it will run, can I put these jars into the system in order to avoid to be downloaded each time the applet is oppened?

The system runs Windows.

The main idea for store these libs in the pc is low bandwidth.

I have tried using proguard in order to compress and reduce code size but it doesn't reduce enough, I need only to download the applet and store all libraries locally.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Tomasz Szuba answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Put all jars into jre/lib/ext/

Thanks.

Comment: Inside the jar? Build an uber-jar and be done with it.

Comment: The main idea for store these libs in the pc is low bandwidth.

Comment: Use Maven shade or proguard to reduce the amount of code and compress it. You surely cannot need 5mb of libraries for an applet!

Comment: I haven't tried Maven but proguard and it doesn't reduce enough the size.

Comment: @vhax what Borris is suggesting is not to compress, but to surgically go in and only copy of those classes you need into your project at build time.  For example, if you're using google guava as a dependency, you very likely don't need all (or the majority) of those classes. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

Comment: I did that using proguard (it have an option to keep only used classes and methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be best to just rely on Java applet caching.
If you specify your applet object with multiple jars, ones that are not changed won't be redownloaded.
For example:

```
<applet codebase ="." code="com.applet.class"
        archive="applet.jar,lib.jar,anotherlib.jar"/>
```

This way if lib.jar and anotherlib.jar are not changed they won't be redownloaded.

If you really must distributed those libs earlier then:

1. Omit those lib from archive attribute
2. Put those libs to extensions library folders. [Instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html)

Other tutorial provides way to automatically instal extension by applet an using one in it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/download.html

Answer (score 1):

For more consistent and reliable caching of Jars, look to deploy the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).